# Unknown class FBSDKProfilePictureView in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, interface-builder, facebook-ios-sdk

When trying to add a view into Main.storyboard and giving it any FBSDK... class like: FBSDKProfilePictureView from the dropdown list.

I'm receiving an error when running the project:
    Unknown class FBSDKProfilePictureView in Interface Builder file.

This is happening in both Swift and Obj-C applications after having no issues adding the framework (4.0.1 version) and implementing login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve if I'm adding an outlet for the desired view than i'm not getting the error anymore and everything seems good.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do what oronbz said or add this code to init() or viewOnLoad() or application start or anywhere really:

```
let _ = FBSDKProfilePictureView()
```

Basically, you just have to manually call the class constructor